# Let $V$ be the set of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ that are orthogonal to $(3, 4, 5)$. Prove that $V$ is a vector space...

Tags: vector-spaces

Question:
Let $V$ be the set of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ that are orthogonal to $(3, 4, 5)$. Prove that $V$ is a vector space, and find a basis for $V$. What is $\dim V$?

Could someone please help with the above question, I am quite confused as how to start.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a vector $(x,y,z)$ in $\Bbb R^3$ is orthogonal to $(3,4,5)$, then their *dot product is zero*:

$$
3x + 4y + 5z = 0.  \label{a}\tag{1}
$$

Thus, if a vector $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $(3,4,5)$, then $x = -\tfrac{4}{3}y - \tfrac{5}{3}z$. The set $V$ of all vectors orthogonal to $(3,4,5)$ is
$$
V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{4}{3}y - \tfrac{5}{3}z\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb R^3\right\} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{4}{3}y \\ y\\ 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{5}{3}z \\ 0\\ z\end{pmatrix}\in \Bbb R^3\right\}.
$$
We can see that the zero vector is in $V$ by putting $y = z = 0$. We can also see that the set is closed under linear combinations since for two solutions $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$ that satisfy $(1)$, the linear combination $\lambda(x,y,z) + \mu(x',y',z')$ also satisfies $(1)$. Hence $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

The dimension of $V$ is the number of vectors in a basis of $V$, and we can see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{4}{3} \\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}-\tfrac{5}{3} \\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a basis of $V$ since any vector in $V$ is a linear combination of these two vectors and they are linearly independent. So the dimension of $V$ is $2.$

Answer (score 0):

Find the equation that describes all vectors, $(a,b,c)$, which perpendicular to (3,4,5). That is a plane equation which goes through the origin. Why is a vector space?